# Importing Steam Community API in Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, steam, unreal-engine4, steamworks-api

So I have my Steamworks SDK imported in my Unreal Engine project. It builds, and on run, I get the Steam overlay. Great!

However, I am now trying to get the user's friends list, which requires the Steam Community API, which is included in two files, `ISteamFriends.h` and `ISteamUtils.h`. I am trying to import those into an Actor class that I created to manage Steam communication, but Visual Studio doesn't see the files and won't build.

```
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Http.h"
#include "ISteamFriends.h"
#include "ISteamUtils.h"
#include "SteamEvents.generated.h"
...
```

This produces the errors:

> error C1083: Cannot open include file 'ISteamFriends.h': No such file or directory
>
> error C1083: Cannot open include file 'ISteamUtils.h': No such file or directory

Is there a specific directory path that I need to give it so that it can find these files? How can I get Visual Studio to find these files so that I can use the Community API?

Comment: Are those files in the current include path?

Comment: @higuaro I really don't know. I just followed [this guide](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Online/Steam/index.html). I know that Steam is in the current project because the overlay pops up, but I don't know if these files are directly accessible because of these instructions or not. Let me dig through the sdk folder and see if I can find the two files I'm trying to import.

Comment: If you're in Visual Studio, then you should set the include file directories for the SDK include (usually .h) files

Comment: @higuaro I'm not sure how familiar you are with Unreal, but the `steam_api.h` file is located here: `C:\Program Files\Epic Games\4.7\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Steamworks\Steamv132\sdk\public\steam` and my project is located in `C:\...\My Documents\Unreal Projects\ProjectName` I'm not sure how to point to that file.

Comment: Depending on your version of Visual Studio, in the Project Properties you should see a section to configure the compiler, there you should find something [like this](http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/help/images/vc10_include.gif), paste there the root path for the files

Comment: @higuaro Brilliant! I just pasted it in there and it built. You sir, deserve an award! If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Don't worry, glad it helped. I just posted the answer to add an additional information regarding the linking section that you should take into account if the sdk contains static library files (.lib files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the directories needed to compile the project (additional includes) are set in the project properties. This can vary depending on the version of Visual Studio, usually is located in `Configuration Properties > C/C++ / General` as depicted in the following image:

[image]

Also be careful to do the same for static libraries if any (`.lib` files); the additional include directories for those are in the *Linker Section*.